# Custom Spring Condition causes java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init>() exception

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm just trying to override the default behaviour of WebSecurityConfiguration and had to write my own conditions to initiate the beans based on the properties defined.
I have defined no arg constructor inside my custom condition class. Irrespective of that, I get `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException`, when I spin up the app.

This is how my code looks:

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnClass(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.class)
@Slf4j
public class WebSecurityConfiguration {

    class DefaultSecurityCondition implements Condition {

        public DefaultSecurityCondition(){}

        @Override
        public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {

            if (context.getEnvironment().getProperty("property.server.authorised-clients") == null &&
                    context.getEnvironment().getProperty("property.server.authorised-thumbprints") == null) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }    


    @Configuration
    @Conditional(DefaultSecurityCondition.class)
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class DefaultAuthorisationConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                    .and().httpBasic().disable().authorizeRequests()
                    .and().csrf().disable();
        }
    }
    }
```

However, when I try to start my app, I get below exception.

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
>   com.test.WebSecurityConfiguration$DefaultSecurityCondition.()

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does the message contain a line number? Also, it looks like the visibility of your class is "package-private", instead of "public", which could cause classes outside of the package to not be able to access your class.

Comment: Even changing the inner class to public didn't fix it. However, when I create `DefaultSecurityCondition` as separate class rather than an inner class, it works fine as intended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When it’s an inner class, `DefaultSecurityCondition` must be declared `static`. When it is not `static` an instance cannot be created without also having an instance of its outer class.